# How can I resolve PyCallGraphException: The command "dot -Tpng -failed with error code 256 error?

Tags: python, pycallgraph

Trying to run the following command to make graph of calls using pycallgraph -

```
pycallgraph graphviz --output-file=/var/www/html/Reports/winmain.png -- token_check.py
```

But I am getting following error when I run the command.

```
pycallgraph.exceptions.PyCallGraphException: The command "dot -Tpng -o/var/www/html/Reports/winmain.png /tmp/tmpVDYnvE" failed with error code 256.
```

Note that I have both 'dot' & graphviz.
Can anyone tell how can I resolve this issue?

This is the complete traceback-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/pycallgraph", line 26, in <module>
exec(__file_content)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycallgraph/pycallgraph.py", line   38, in __exit__
self.done()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycallgraph/pycallgraph.py", line 81, in done
self.stop()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycallgraph/pycallgraph.py", line 90, in generate
output.done()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycallgraph/output/graphviz.py", line 112, in done
'code %(ret)i.' % locals())
 pycallgraph.exceptions.PyCallGraphException: The command "dot -Tpng -o/var/www/html/Reports/winmain.png /tmp/tmpVDYnvE" failed with error code 256.
```

Comment: Do you have permission to write to the current directory?

Comment: Also, please can you include the whole Traceback for the following problem.

Comment: @Kyrylo What current? Do you mean in tmp?

Comment: Yes. See [this](https://github.com/gak/pycallgraph/issues/100).

Comment: @Kyrylo Edited. included traceback.

Comment: Thank you @Kyrylo But unfortunately it didn't help. I have installed both from pip.

Comment: Can you try to output file to your home folder?

Comment: @Kyrylo You mean to hack their code?

Comment: Can you specify the output to y

Comment: What y? @Kyrylo

Comment: Sorry, I was out of my computer. Can you try to set `output file` into your home folder? Maybe some problems in permissions under `/var/www/...` folder

Comment: Try in terminal `dot -Tpng -o/var/www/html/Reports/winmain.png /tmp/tmpVDYnvE`. Then you might want to create those folders that are not there.

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me

Go to `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycallgraph/output/graphviz.py`

Add a space between `-o` and the argument. That is ,

Change around line 102

```
cmd = '{} -T{} -o{} {}'.format(
            self.tool, self.output_type, self.output_file, temp_name
        )
```

to

```
cmd = '{} -T{} -o {} {}'.format(
            self.tool, self.output_type, self.output_file, temp_name
        )
```

Comment: Did not fix it for me. My run command is: `pycallgraph graphviz --  run.py`

Comment: In such a case, you have to add another space between `-T` and the argument. But the error persists